# Convert from UNIX Epoch to Date String

Tags: objective-c

How do I convert from a unix epoch integer to date string?

Comment: Use google, this is really simple.

Comment: No need to vote down just because of teh lazy.  however, the answer may be quite different depending on need and target platform.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Code:

```
NSUInteger *foo = 123456789;
NSString *bar = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:foo] description];
```

**PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE** be user-friendly and show the date according to the locale of the user: [Cocoa - Localized string from NSDate, NSCalendarDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011175/cocoa-localized-string-from-nsdate-nscalendardate)

Comment: Not a big deal, but you'll confuse the newbs and crash your app with that pointer to an integer. You should also ideally use NSTimeIntervals, which map to doubles, for the input to that method, though the compiler will take care of it for you.